# rvest html_node returns empty list

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I was trying to scrape a webpage using the R package rvest but when I use the command html_node it returns an empty list. What is the problem? This is my code (I used SelectorGadget to obtain the tags):

```
#SETUP
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

#Getting the link for each house

main.link<- "https://www.sreality.cz/en/search/for-sale/apartments/praha"

main.page<-read_html(main.link)

links<-  html_nodes(main.page, css=".title .ng-binding")
```

As you can see I am a beginner in R. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: this page is a complex one (ajax or someting else). There is nothing in page source. You must try selenium package.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with RSelenium as Selcuk Akbas suggests:

```
#Loading the rvest package
library(rvest)
library(magrittr) # for the '%>%' pipe symbols
library(RSelenium) # to get the loaded html of 

# starting local RSelenium (this is the only way to start RSelenium that is working for me atm)
selCommand <- wdman::selenium(jvmargs = c("-Dwebdriver.chrome.verboseLogging=true"), retcommand = TRUE)
shell(selCommand, wait = FALSE, minimized = TRUE)
remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4567L, browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()

#Specifying the url for desired website to be scrapped
main_link<- "https://www.sreality.cz/en/search/for-sale/apartments/praha"

# go to website
remDr$navigate(main_link)

# get page source and save it as an html object with rvest
main_page <- remDr$getPageSource(header = TRUE)[[1]] %>% read_html()

# get the links
links<-  html_nodes(main_page, css=".title .ng-binding")
```

Hope it helps! Happy scraping!